# TSql Pivot or Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have seen various posts on Pivot or converting rows to columns, but still i have not luck with it so i have decided to post the question.

My table **cols** is

`Id  col_name 
 1   Serial
 2   Data1
 3   Data2`

My table **rows** is

`Id  col_id value
 1    1      1
 2    1      2
 3    1      3
 4    2      25
 5    2      26
 6    2      27
 7    3      28
 8    3      29
 9    3      30`

I want the result as below i think using unpivot or pivot might work. The out come should be something like -

`Serial Data1 Data2
 1        25   28
 2        26   29
 3        27   30`

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Can you post the query which you have tried so far

Comment: what exactly is linking the 2 tables ?

Comment: Sorry, id in cols table and col_id(foreign key) in rows table is the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `pivot` is useful here. Try this

```
WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Id) RN,
                value            AS Data1
         FROM   yourtable
         WHERE  col_id = 1),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Id) RN,
                value            AS Data2
         FROM   yourtable
         WHERE  col_id = 2),
     cte3
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY Id) RN,
                value            AS Data3
         FROM   yourtable
         WHERE  col_id = 3)
SELECT Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY a.rn) AS serial,
       Data1,
       Data2,
       Data3
FROM   cte1 A
       FULL OUTER JOIN cte2 B
                    ON a.RN = b.RN
       FULL OUTER JOIN cte3 C
                    ON b.RN = C.RN
```

Comment: your full join should include CTE1 in both cases. Otherwise you are missing data if table b doesn't have data. I would also make first full join into a left join

Comment: Hey fireblade, your solution is right on target, but i think i need to build dynamic sql when the number of columns is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

I will point out that your datamodel need some improvement, so my method to join serial is improvised and can't be trusted in a real life project, there is no logical connection between your tables. Here is how to pivot your data:

```
;WITH [rows] AS
(
  SELECT id, value, col_id
  FROM 
    (values
    (1,1,1),(2,1,2),
    (3,1,3),(4,2,25),
    (5,2,26),(6,2,27),
    (7,3,28),(8,3,29),
    (9,3,30)) x(Id, col_id, value)
), cols as
(
  SELECT cols.id, col_name
  FROM
    (values
      ( 2, 'Data1'),( 3, 'Data2')) 
      cols(Id, col_name)
), result as
(
  SELECT row_number() OVER (partition by col_id order by [rows].id) rn, col_name, value
  FROM
    cols
  JOIN
    [rows]
  ON [rows].col_id = cols.id
  WHERE cols.id > 1
)
SELECT rn Serial, Data1, Data2
FROM
  result
PIVOT
(min([value])  
FOR col_name
in([Data1],[Data2])  
)AS p
```

Result:

```
Serial Data1 Data2
1      25    28
2      26    29
3      27    30
```